# ODBC driven ASP.NET application running on iis doesn't work on speceific system

Tags: asp.net, iis, odbc

I'm having a strange problem with IIS, asp.net and ODBC.
My application is driven by SQL server via ODBC driver (I know it's bad practice, but my entire DAL is already written and will not be changed). 
The problem is that when I run an SP with my web interface, on any other computer other than the production server it works fine, but on the production server I get the following error:

**Exception Message: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000] [Microsoft]   [ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to int**

Obviously when I run it under management studio it works fine.
I think the problem is somewhere between the IIS and the odbc driver, but I'm not sure exactly where.

I'm running .net framework 4.

This is the calling method:

```
ODBCComm command = new ODBCComm();          
        command.Query = "SP_web_update_calls_dest @id=?,@name=? ,@ivrCode=?,@DDI=?,@destType=?,@trkGroup=?,@result=? output";
        command.AddInputParam(id);
        return AddParamsAndExecute(name, ivrCode, DDI, destType, trkGroup, command);
```

it basically wraps arround:
    OdbcCommand.ExecuteDirect();

Thanks a lot,
    Yuval.

Comment: Can you include the method throwing the error and the stored proc/sql being called?

Comment: I edited it in. thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: Gonna need the stored proc SP_web_update_calls_dest and the variable types for id, name, ivrCode, DDI, destType and trkGroup

Comment: There you go: name nvarchar(50), id int, ivrCode int, DDI varchar(15), @destType int, trkGroup int, result int out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
I think I solved it.
There were actually 2 problems, and I'm not exactly sure what caused them.
Anyway, I switched the ODBC driver to SQL Server Native Client 10. 
This basically solved the problem, but for some reason it doesn't support the output modifier in queries so I had to remove that.

So I got it solved, but still have no idea what caused the problem. I'm guessing it has something to do with different versions of drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your first param is being used in the ID spot.  I'm not sure why this would work in pre-production and fail only in production, but try this instead...

```
ODBCComm command = new ODBCComm();           
        command.Query = "SP_web_update_calls_dest @id=?,@name=? ,@ivrCode=?,@DDI=?,@destType=?,@trkGroup=?,@result=? output"; 

        return AddParamsAndExecute(id, name, ivrCode, DDI, destType, trkGroup, command);
```

---

I have no idea what ODBCComm is or what AddParamsAndExecute does because you haven't included the relavant code, however, here's what the request *should* look like:

```
    OdbcCommand Cmd = new OdbcCommand("SP_web_update_calls_dest", _Connection); 
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OdbcType.Int); 
    Cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = id; 

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OdbcType.NVarChar); 
    Cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@ivrCode", OdbcType.Int); 
    Cmd.Parameters["@ivrCode"].Value = ivrCode; 

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@DDI", OdbcType.VarChar); 
    Cmd.Parameters["@DDI"].Value = DDI;

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@destType", OdbcType.Int); 
    Cmd.Parameters["@destType"].Value = destType; 

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@trkGroup", OdbcType.Int); 
    Cmd.Parameters["@trkGroup"].Value = trkGroup; 

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", OdbcType.Int); 
    Cmd.Parameters["@result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    int result = (int)Cmd.Parameters["@result"].Value;
```

Comment: I think you missed this line:
    command.AddInputParam(id);
Or in other words, the id param is added outside the AddParamsAndExecute method.

Comment: No, I didn't miss it. I moved it to "AddParamsAndExecute".  I'm unclear what the method does, but I'm guessing it adds the params to the command object before it executes it.

Comment: Yeah, it looks almost exactly like yours only I wrap cmd with my own wrapper for a more convenient interface, Although I don't specify param names and just let them fill out according to order.

Perhaps it's a matter of configuration?

Comment: Maybe you should add an overload that accepts Command Parameters so you can specify the param names.  I think the command object is confused somehow and putting your nvarchar param as the first param, instead of the second.  This would explain the error.